# Why git checkout of a past commit puts untracked files in my working directory?

Tags: git

I would expect that checking out should not put untracked files in my working directory. Why is this happening?

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$ git checkout 7dfd
Note: checking out '7dfd'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b new_branch_name

HEAD is now at 7dfd765... weeeee
$ git status
HEAD detached at 7dfd765
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    rel/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: Perhaps the content of `.gitignore` changed?

Comment: Maybe `rel` *is* untracked, but was not in `.gitignore` at that point?